# bind() and unbind() in click() function

Tags: javascript, jquery

**I have this code:**

```
$('#people_nav>.prev, #people_nav>.next').click(function(){

   // Here I need to disable event of click for needed elements, see code below
   $('#people_nav>.prev, #people_nav>.next').unbind('click');

   ...
   code
   ...

   // Here I need resume event for click() function. How?

});
```

How can I resume event for `click()` function? It should be in body of `click(function(){...});`...

Comment: What do you mean "resume" ? Do you want to temporarily disable any click events or do you specifically want the event to be halted and then resumed?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and [`off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) for that, and a named function

```
var elements = $('#people_nav > .prev, #people_nav > .next');

elements.on('click', doStuff); // bind handler

function doStuff() {

    elements.off('click');  // unbind handler

    /*...
    code
    ...*/

    elements.on('click', doStuff);  // rebind handler
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a named function. Something like

```
var element = $('#people_nav>.prev, #people_nav>.next'); //cache for better performance
var yourFunction = function () {
    // Here I need to disable event of click for needed elements, see code below
    element.off('click'); //unbind event
        ...
    code
        ...
    // Here I need resume event for click() function. How?
    element.click(yourFunction);
};
element.click(yourFunction);
```

However, I would recommend the use of [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and [`off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use [`off`](http://api.jquery.com/off/)

```
$('#people_nav>.prev, #people_nav>.next').off('click');
```

If jquery version >= 1.7 prefer `on` and `off` methods instead of `bind` and `unbind` methods